# C++ - Error: 'list' does not name a type (list object as member variable in class)

Tags: c++, class, stdlist

I have been running into the "'xxx' does not name a type" error a lot and most posts I've read before have mentioned that this error occurs with some dependency issues.  However, I can't seem to find mine.  Here's what I got:

*GameLib.h*

```
#ifndef GAMELIB_H_
#define GAMELIB_H_

//Structures
struct player_t {
    std::string name;
    int MMR;
};

//Prototypes
void* queueUpPlayer(void*);
int randomMMR();
std::string randomName();

#endif /* GAMELIB_H_ */
```

*PlayerGroup.h*

```
#ifndef GROUP_H_
#define GROUP_H_

class playerGroup {
private:
    std::list<player_t> players;
    std::list<player_t>::iterator it;
    const int totalSize = 10;

public:
    //Constructor
    playerGroup();

    //Destructor
    ~playerGroup();

    //Add
    void add(const player_t p);

    ....
};

#endif /* GROUP_H_ */
```

*PlayerGroup.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <list>

#include "GameLib.h"
#include "playerGroup.h"

using namespace std;

playerGroup::playerGroup() {}

playerGroup::~playerGroup() {}

void playerGroup::add(const player_t p) {
    if(players.size() >= totalSize) exit(1);
    players.push_back(p);
}

.....
```

I'm recieving this error on both the lists member variables in the PlayerGroup class:

```
..\src\PlayerGroup.h:13:2: error: 'list' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
..\src\PlayerGroup.h:14:2: error: 'list' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
```

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Comment: You need to `#include <list>` in `PlayerGroup.h`.

Comment: You should be including `<list>` before using `std::list`. Do you expect any file that includes that header to randomly include it for you before including your header? I hope not. Same for `std::string`.

Comment: I thought including the necessary files in the .cpp would also be included in the header file.  Is that assumption incorrect then?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe you need to `#include <list>` in your PlayerGroup.h file because it is used in that file.

Comment: Are there any downsides or side effects to including files in your header files?  (I've never knew you could include files in a header file)

Comment: No, there shouldn't be any kind of downsides. Just like using an #include in your .cpp file, it is so that a certain file can be linked with another header file to use its implementation. In this case, only using #include in the .cpp file should only give the .cpp file use of its methods.

Comment: @JoeG There are some downsides actually. If you have a large project and include headers into headers thoughtlessly you may produce a lot of unnecessary dependencies and possibly needlessly increase your compilation time. Though if you store some objects in class (not pointers to objects) there's nothing you can do about it except maybe using precompiled header containing often used headers.